# Billy and Bob start with two rectangular grid which can be modeled as a chocolate

Tags: combinatorics, recreational-mathematics, puzzle, combinatorial-game-theory

> Billy and Bob start with two rectangular grid which can be modeled as
> a chocolate. They take turns cutting and eating the chocolate: on
> their turn, they can cut the chocolate along an edge parallel to the
> sides (thus resulting in three rectangles) and consume one of the
> three pieces, so that his partner has two chocolates, and therefore
> can make an analogous move. A player loses if they cannot make a cut.
> Assuming optimal play, who wins if:
>
> (a) the starting rectangles are $1\times 2020$ and $2\times 4040$,
> (b) the starting rectangles are $100\times100$ and $100\times 500$, and
> (c) generalize.

My friend and I tested the first case (a) extensively, and ended up with somewhat of a mirroring thing if there are two $1\times n$ rectangles resultant. However, if $n$ is even one player could theoretically cut the $1\times n$ into two $1\times\frac n2$ rectangles, and discord the other $1\times n$.

I don't know how to continue.

Comment: You may need to work out the [Sprague-Grundy numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sprague%E2%80%93Grundy_theorem) for small boards to start.

Comment: seems to be https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chomp

Comment: @WillJagy It's not chomp. your cut has to travel the entire length of the board, and there are multiple rectangles at play, etc. the game mechanics differ a lot.

Comment: @WillJagy I don't think so.  You never have three pieces in chomp, do you?  (Although I don't understand how a cut parallel to an edge results in three pieces.)

Comment: So the game starts with $2$ rectangles. On each turn, a player can split one of them to create another rectangle, and then eat any one of the $3$, leaving $2$ rectangles for the next player. Am I getting this right?

Comment: "on their turn, they can cut the chocolate along an edge parallel to the sides (thus resulting in three rectangles)"  .... Um, wouldn't that result in *two* pieces of chocolate

Comment: @fleablood if you have two rectangles, and split one of them, then wouldn't you now have three?

Comment: Okay... the what does a line parrallel the side mean?  What *side*?  Which chocolate?

Comment: You're presented with two rectangles. You choose one of them, split it into two rectangular pieces by means of a straight cut all the way across from one edge to the opposite edge; now, you temporarily have three rectangles. You choose one, eat it, and present the remaining two to your opponent. The game proceeds. I guess it should be mentioned that everything is integers.

Comment: I've figured out so far that if both pieces have one dimension less than 2, the beginning player can always win unless you have any of the following configurations. $1\times n | 1 \times n$ for $n$ containing an even number of factors of $2$. Or $1\times n | 2 \times 2n$ for $n$ containing an even number of factors of $2$. Or $2\times n| 2 \times n$ for $n$ containing an odd number of factors of $2$. I was able to prove this, but I couldn't figure out the generalization. So the answer to a is the second player can always win.

Comment: @jMdA I see you solved (a). It seems that $n\times n, n\times n$ starting rectangles is always a loss for the beginning player. This would imply that $n\times n, n\times m$ starting rectangles is always a win for the beginning player, which would answer (b). This loss pattern also implies that $n\times p,n\times q$ is a win for the beginning player if $p+q=n$.

Comment: Let $f((a,b),(c,d))\in\{0,1\}$ determine if the beginning player {loses, wins} the game when starting rectangles are of dimensions $a\times b$, $c\times d$. I conjecture that the following holds for all $a\ne b\ne c\ne d$. $$\begin{align}f((a,a),(a,a)) &= 0, \\f((a,a),(b,b)) &= 0, \\f((a,b),(a,b)) &= (v_2(a)\bmod2)\oplus (v_2(b)\bmod2), \\f((a,b),(a,c)) &= 1, \\f((a,a),(b,c)) &= 1, \\f((a,b),(c,d)) &= g((a,b),(c,d)).\end{align}$$ Here, $v_2(n)$ counts how many times $2$ divides $n$ and $\oplus$ is XOR. (It remains to find $g$, a solution for when all dimensions of rectangles are distinct.)

Comment: What is the source of the problem? The general case where all dimensions of rectangles are distinct, looks hard. For instance, I found patterns that follow sequences based on binary representations of dimensions like if x = [A157971](https://oeis.org/A157971) then $1\times 3,x\times(x+2)$ is a loss for the beginning player and otherwise $1\times 3,y\times z$ is a win. But, I also found patterns that do not follow any sequences in OEIS.

Comment: @vepir I have a conjecture for a general rule. Let $(e_0,e_1,\dots)=(1,3,4,5,\dots)$ be the increasing sequence of all integers whose prime factorization has an even number of twos, same for $(d_0,d_1,\dots)=(2,6,8,10,\dots)$. Then the losing positions are those of the form, for nonnegative integers $n,m,k$,
$$
(e_n,e_{n\oplus k}),(e_m,e_{m\oplus k})\\
(e_n,e_{n\oplus k}),(d_m,d_{m\oplus k})\\
(d_n,d_{n\oplus k}),(d_m,d_{m\oplus k})
$$where $\oplus$ is nim-sum. The data for all positions with max dimension $24$ confirms this https://repl.it/@mearnest/Game-with-two-chocolate-bars#main.py

Comment: When $k=0$, you get positions where both bars are squares. When $n=m$, you recover the $(a,b)(a,b)$ where $v_2(a)\equiv v_2(b)\pmod 2$ positions you had.

Comment: @MikeEarnest That should be turned into an answer. Now that you've found a characterisation of the losing positions, it seems straightforward to verify that it works. Any non-losing position with a $d\times e$ rectangle can be made losing by halving the $d$. In any non-losing position without such a rectangle you can reduce one side, doing a nim move on the indices to make it losing. Lastly, any move on a losing position makes it non-losing by creating a $d\times e$ rectangle or changing one index.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I will write each game position as an ordered quadruple $(a,b,c,d)$, meaning an $a\times b$ bar and a $c\times d$ bar.

Call a number *vile* if it has an even number of twos in its prime factorization, and *dopey* if it has an odd number of twos. This terminology was originally conceived by [Fraenkel](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0012365X11001427).

Let $(e_0,e_1,e_2,\dots)=(1,3,4,5,\dots)$ denote the sorted, zero-indexed list of vile numbers, and let $(d_0,d_1,d_2,\dots)=(2,6,8,10,\dots)$ be the sorted list of dopey numbers. Finally, let $f(n)$ denote the index of $n$ in its list, regardless if that list is $e$ or $d$. That is, $f(3)=1$, $f(10)=3$, $f(4)=f(8)=2$.

> Let $S$ be the of positions $(a,b,c,d)$  where all of these conditions are satisfied:
>
> - $a$ and $b$ have the same type (both vile or both dopey).
> - $c$ and $d$ have the same type.
> - $f(a)\oplus f(b)\oplus f(c)\oplus f(d)=0$, where $\oplus$ is the nim-sum.
>
> A position is losing if and only if it is in $S$.

I found this pattern with help of Vepir and a computer program, while Jaap Scherphuis came up with the proof of its correctness.

We need to show that any move from $S$ results in a position outside of $S$, and every position not in $S$ has a legal move to $S$. First, here is the winning strategy to take any position outside $S$ to one in $S$:

- Suppose $a$ and $b$ have different types, WLOG $a$ is vile and $b$ is dopey. A winning move is to cut the $a\times b$ bar in half perpendicularly to the $b$ side, and eat the other bar, leaving the position $(a,b/2,a,b/2)$. Since $b$ is dopey, it follows that $b/2$ is vile, so it is easy to check the nim-sum condition and verify this position is in $S$.
   The same logic applies when $c$ and $d$ have different types.
- Otherwise, you will have $f(a)\oplus f(b)\oplus f(c) \oplus f(d)\neq 0$. The idea is to make a move which changes a single index of one of the coordinates, without changing its type, and which reduces the index corresponding to the winning move on the nim game with heap sizes $f(a),f(b),f(c),f(d)$.

Now, suppose $(a,b,c,d)\in S$. Any move where you eat one of the pieces from the bar you broke will change exactly one of the coordinates. This necessarily leaves a position outside of $S$, because for any choice of three coordinates, there is a unique choice of a fourth coordinate for which the position is in $S$. Therefore, we restrict out attention to moves where you eat the bar you did not break, of the form
$$
(a,b,c,d)\implies (a',b,a-a',b)
$$
where $1\le a' \le a-1$. In order for this new position to be in $S$, $a'$ and $a-a'$ must both have the same type as $b$, and it must be true that $f(a')=f(a-a')$. If $a'$ and $a-a'$ have the same type and index, they must be equal, so the move would have to be $(a/2, b,a/2,b)$. But $a/2$ has the opposite type of $a$, so this is not in $S$.

Comment: Very nicely done! I had not fleshed out all the details of the proof, but you did it more cleanly than what I was thinking of.